# How come my locationManager is returning zero for latitude and longitude?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, core-location

I am trying to obtain GPS location. I am running the iOS simulator and setting a custom location

[image]

My header file I define the locationManager.

[image]

In my ViewController Class I synthesize the locationManager.

[image]

In my viewDidLoad I implement the locationManager

[image]

In my trigger Method, I try to log out the location data. I get 0.

[image]

```
2015-03-22 11:21:24.539 APP_NAME[50197:558692] Lat: 0
2015-03-22 11:21:24.540 APP_NAME[50197:558692] Long: 0
```

**UPDATE**
I just tested on my iPod touch and had the same problem.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate. That post really helped. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, in the future, please refrain from including pictures for source code. Insert the actual source code and indent it (which you can do by pressing the "{}" button while the code is selected) to make sure your formatting is preserved. If you use images, the question is not searchable. Also, if someone wanted to reproduce your error, rather than cutting and pasting, they have to type it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I am aware of the source but in this instance I felt it necessary to provide insight into whether Xcode reported errors.